# Using 'this' as Context in the init block of activity?

Tags: android, kotlin, constructor, nullpointerexception, initialization

I am developing an android application with kotlin.

I have a `DereDatabaseHelper` class which has `init` block that uses a `context` given through *class parameter(?)*

The `DereDatabaseHelper` is like this.

```
class DereDatabaseHelper(context: Context) {
    val manifestFile: File
    val fumensDBFile: File
    val fumenFolder: File

    val musicIDToInfo: MutableMap<Int, MusicInfo> = HashMap()
    val fumenIDToMusicID: SparseIntArray = SparseIntArray()

    init {
        val datadir = context.getExternalFilesDir(null).parentFile.parentFile
```

The `DereDatabaseHelper` class is instantiated here in `SongListActivity` like this.

```
class SongListActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    var dereDatabaseHelper : DereDatabaseHelper
    init {
        dereDatabaseHelper = DereDatabaseHelper(this)
    }
```

I thought that this code was correct, but this codes throws `NullPointerException`.

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>
> 'java.io.File android.content.Context.getExternalFilesDir(java.lang.String)'
>
> on a null object reference at
>
> android.content.ContextWrapper.getExternalFilesDir(ContextWrapper.java:253)
>           at com.kyhsgeekcode.dereinfo.model.DereDatabaseHelper.<init>(DereDatabaseHelper.kt:21)
>           at com.kyhsgeekcode.dereinfo.SongListActivity.<init>(SongListActivity.kt:31)

**Is `this` null when the execution is in `init` block and what initialization style should I use to fix this?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Never use the constructor of an Activity to do anything that involves the Context. Android instantiates Activities using their sole empty constructor (via reflection), and then sets up the activity's various fields *before* it ever calls `onCreate()`. Your first safe entry point to do anything in your Activity is in `onCreate()`.

You also can't call methods of the Activity (which is itself a Context) in the constructor.

You also can't use the context in any way to even set up properties, because they'll try to access the context before `onCreate`:

```
class MyActivity: AppCompatActivity() {
    val assets: AssetManager = getAssets() // This will cause a crash
}
```

To avoid having to make your property nullable, you can do either of the following, which allow you to avoid having your class instantiated until after `onCreate()` is called:

```
class SongListActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var dereDatabaseHelper : DereDatabaseHelper

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate
        dereDatabaseHelper = DereDatabaseHelper(this)
    }
```

or

```
class SongListActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    val dereDatabaseHelper by lazy { DereDatabaseHelper(this) }
}
```

Comment: Now I understand that it is not a good idea to do anyhing in Activity's constructors and the `init` block(are `init` and constructor same?). But then now I wonder why it caused NullPointerException, because `this` should not be `null` anyway in java, even if in constructor. Do you mean "`this` as Context" is `null` because it is not yet fully initialized?

Comment: No, the `this` you pass to your DereDatabaseHelper constructor is not null. But internally, `Activity.getExternalFilesDir()` is calling `mBase.getExternalFilesDir()`, and `mBase` (a Java-default-scoped instance of Context) is still null because it hasn't been assigned yet. So the NullPointerException is not happening in your own code.

Answer (score 1):

Activities are not completely initialized by the `constructor` or in your case `init` block.

Android system initializes activities and then calls the `onCreate` method. So you should do the following

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
 // create instance of DareDatabaseHelper 
}
```

**Why it doesn't work with the constructor?**

consider the following code snippet

```
var myActivity = MyActivity() // This doesn't start MainActivity

// This is how you start an activity
val intent = Intent(context, MyActivity::class.java)
startActivity(intent)
```

***When you start any activity you never instantiate the activity class, why?***

Because that is the responsibility of android system, when you do `startActivity(intent)` android system instantiates your `activity` class using the default `constructor` and then does all the initialization (ie. providing `context`) And once the `activity` is completely initialized the `onCreate` method of your activity is called where you can do your end of initialization.

Comment: Do you mean that android does not just instantiate my `Activity` class and then call `onCreate` but call `onCreate` while instantiating my `Activity` class?

Comment: Thank you for your updated answer and detailed explanation, mightyWOZ!